# Newbie Movie clip in website

Tags: movieclip

I'm totally familiar in making static and dynamic websites.
However, I have never dealt with multimedia in a website.
I want to build a static website that has movies placed on various pages.
The movies will be supplied to me (I will not be making them), I only need to place them on pages.

My questions are...What format (file type) should the movie be in (I am not familiar with Flash, is that a movie type file?, are there others?)

I have the option to tell the people making the movies what type to make. What should I say, and should I include a size range (I'm assuming its sort of like an image file?)

Once I have the above things worked out, I'm assuming I'll have some movie files. Is placing them on a page just like placing image files?

Any help in getting me going is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload them to http://www.blip.tv, and they will give you HTML embeddable code for your site. You can upload mov, wmv, etc, all to Blip. They will convert it for you and handle the dirty-work. All you'll have to do is copy/paste the HTML code they provide.

Comment: I was just looking at Blip, and it seems great. To be clear, I will have maybe 10 +/- movies, and all I need to do is upload them, then grab the HTML to embed them? I do not care about making money, so I do not have to do that, do I? And, no matter the movie file type/size, they "fix" it so I may link to it?

Comment: Yup                           .

Answer (score 1):

The best way, in my humble opinion, is to embed video files uploaded to [YouTube](http://youtube.com/), [Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/) or other video uploading websites.

Comment: thanks, Alan...a follow up question...if i have the movie clip makers upload the video to YouTube, it is easy to embed the newly made YouTube in a web page?

Comment: Embeding movies from YouTube is very easy. Each movie page has the code to copy/paste located to the right of the video.

Comment: Be warned though, YouTube will plaster "YOUTUBE" on your video and your video player - go with blip as I suggested and you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This generates HTML for embedding common multimedia types:

http://cit.ucsf.edu/embedmedia/step1.php

You can look at those for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with Flash movies is they won't play on iPhones.

Answer (score 0):

One word, Youtube

http://help.youtube.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=132460